# Create some logic to join a site collection

Tags: list, list-item, script-webpart

I would like to create some "join" button on each site collection. A visitor can press on this button if he would like to join this site collection. I would like to add some list item with the username of the current user. Is this possible in for example a content editor webpart or a script webpart? There is only one issue and that is that the current user is a visitor and dont has contribute permissions in the list "JoinRequests".

Comment: Can you check if the user can try to trigger site workflow from the JOIN button. Site workflow can may be creating list item or start anther workflow to create list item.

Comment: How about using the access request functionality? It can be turned on and configured on group level. Link to you a specific group can be created and used as a button link.

Comment: Which access request functionality?

Comment: there is OOTB functionality, if user gets the access denied error then SharePoint provide a link to request the access.

Comment: All users has read permissions on all site collections. So they will not receive an access denied. I would like to implement some functionality where end users can request contribute permissions.